# Python Script requires plot to close before continuing

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a Python Script which is producing a plot, everything works fine. But I would like to keep this plot open (to compare it with others), this doesn't work, the script doesn't continue to run until I have closed the plot window. Any suggestions what I can do? Thanks :)

Comment: Turn on interactive mode. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.ion()`

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but now the new plot is in the same window, so i still can't Keep the old one.

Comment: Initialise a new figure before each plot. `plt.figure()`. Alternatively, be more explicit on which axis you are plotting stuff: `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2); ax1.plot(x1, y1); ax2.plot(x2, y2)`.

Comment: Thank you :) and which ordering is correct? because now I get Windows which don't have any Content as well...

Comment: I am no psychic. Without seeing your code it's impossible to tell. Presumably, you are initialising too many new figures now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `plt.show()` the event loop is transfered to the window shown. The rest of the program will only continue once that window is closed.

The suggestion would be to simply call `plt.show()` at the end of the script, when all figures are ready to be shown at once.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `plt.ion()` instead of `plt.show()` the script will continue to run without you needing to close the window and the plot will update in the open window.

Alternatively, you can use `plt.show(block=False)`

Comment: This is better answer than the one accepted.